# Allow users to enter letters and numbers only in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

I want to use this regular expression `/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/`

But with the condition:

- The word must start with a letter and not with a number
- Do not allow special characters

I have tried use another method `/[a-z]*$/i` but it doesn't seem working. Any help will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a negative lookahead to assert not a digit or space at the start of the string.

Using a case insensitive match:

```
re = /\A(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)?\z/i
```

**Explanation**

- `\A` Start of string
- `(?![\d ])` Negative lookahead, assert not either a space or digit directly to the right
- `[a-z\d ]*` Optionally repeat matching any of the listed
- `\z` End of string

See a [regex rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/AeEBy1GLetaLtD).

Answer (score 2):

You can re-vamp the regex to

```
/\A(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)?\z/
```

If the space is a special char, remove it from the regex.

Note that in Ruby, start of string is matched with `\A` and end of string is matched with `\z`.

See the [**Rubular demo**](https://rubular.com/r/psxWFhCHAaDp5S).

*Details*:

- `\A` - start of string
- `(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)?` - an optional sequence of
- `[a-zA-Z]`  - an ASCII letter
- `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*` - zero or more spaces, ASCII letters or digits
- `\z` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer already, although I'd change the whole `a-zA-Z` thing to just an `a-z` with a `i` flag on the regex, just more concise.

Another alternative, which I personally find a bit more expressive, is to use something like:

```
str.starts_with? /[a-z]/i and not str.match /[^a-z0-9]/i
```

And finally, I wonder if you'd like to also allow non-ASCII alphabetic characters, like a é or whatever?  In which case you'd want to use `[:alpha:]` and `[:alnum:]` like this:

```
str.starts_with? /[[:alpha:]]/ and not str.match /[^[:alnum:]]/
```